# Describe $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals, zariski-topology

I want to describe $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n))$. For starters, I know that since $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, then $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is a PID, and therefore the only prime ideal in $\mathbb{R}[x]$ is $(x)$. Due to the correspondence between the ideals of a ring and a quotient ring, I presume $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n))$ has only one element, but I don't know how to describe it. Can someone help me?

Comment: You have done it yourself: it is a one-point space

Comment: It's often called a fuzzy/fat/double/triple/etc. point as well, whose degree of fuzziness/fatness is given by $n$. The scheme $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{k}[x]/(x^2))$ is a classical example. I think it's dealt with in, e.g., Vakil's notes but I don't remember exactly (it's everywhere though).

Comment: @AlexeyKubanov what point is that though?

Comment: You already said that $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x)$ is an integral domain / field

Comment: It's not true that the only prime ideal in R[x] is (x).

Answer (score 2):

Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n)$ be the canonical projection. If $\mathfrak{p}\in{\rm Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n))$ then $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})\in{\rm Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x])$ therefore there exists $Q\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ irreducible such that $\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})=(Q)$. Since $0\in\mathfrak{p}$, $(x^n)=\pi^{-1}(0)\subseteq\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})=(Q)$ therefore $Q$ divides $x^n$ and since $Q$ is irreducible, $Q=x$. Since $\pi$ is surjective, we have
$$ \mathfrak{p}=\pi(\pi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}))=(x) $$
On the other hand, $(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n))/(x)\simeq\mathbb{R}[x]/(x)\simeq\mathbb{R}$ so clearly $(x)\in{\rm Spec}(\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^n))$.

Comment: I do not understand why $(x^n)=\pi^{-1}(0)$

Comment: $\pi$ sends $P$ to $P\pmod{x^n}$, therefore $P\in\pi^{-1}(0)\iff P\equiv 0\pmod 
 {x^n}\iff x^n | P \iff P\in(x^n)$